# Netbeans wizard Entity Classes from Database, not all tables mapped

Tags: netbeans, entity, wizard

I used this wizard to create entity classes from my database. Some tables have not been transformed into classes, but there are attributes that identify the relationships.

[this is my db ERD](http://postimg.org/image/gwq2co8zv/) (mysql)

and this is the user entity class (attributes)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByOid", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.oid = :oid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAddress", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.address = :address"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findBySince", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.since = :since")})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "oid")
    private Integer oid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "since")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date since;
    @JoinTable(name = "favorite", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "wheelchair_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid")})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Wheelchair> wheelchairList;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userList1")
    private List<Wheelchair> wheelchairList1;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "senderOid")
    private List<Comment> commentList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Role roleOid;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userOid")
    private List<Orthopedy> orthopedyList;

    public User() {
    }
...
```

i can't understand something:
where is the OWN join table?
why i have userList1 and wheelchairList1? should it identifies OWN table? in this case i can rename it here or i have to rename it in some xml file?
why of

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userOid")
    private List<Orthopedy> orthopedyList;
```

?
it should be OneToOne...

moreover the "JSF from entities class" wizard creates CRUD operation to manage Users, how can i manage join tables? I need to write something in the controller like what?

can you please link me some resource where i can learn this?

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Creating Entities It Creates Classes For All Tables With Primary Key
But not for tables that have many to many relations . its managed by their parent classes it is maintained as a list.

This is my code for managing my many to many table of  SubjectFaculty which has details of Faculty and Subjects

Assigning A Subject To Faculty

```
public void assignFacultyToSubject(String facultyUname, Integer subjectId) {
    try {
        Subject oSubject = em.find(Subject.class, subjectId);
        Faculty oFaculty = em.find(Faculty.class, facultyUname);

        College oCollege = em.find(College.class, oFaculty.getCollegeUname().getCollegeUname());

        List<Faculty> lstFaculty = oSubject.getFacultyList();
        List<Subject> lstSubject = oFaculty.getSubjectList();

        if (!lstSubject.contains(oSubject)) {
            lstFaculty.add(oFaculty);
            lstSubject.add(oSubject);

            oSubject.setFacultyList(lstFaculty);
            oFaculty.setSubjectList(lstSubject);
            em.merge(oSubject);
            em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entry Already Found");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error :- " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Removing Subject And Faculty Details Form Many to Many Table

```
@Override
public void removeFacultySubject(String facultyUname, Integer subjectId) {
    try {
        Subject oSubject = em.find(Subject.class, subjectId);
        Faculty oFaculty = em.find(Faculty.class, facultyUname);

        List<Subject> lstSubject = oFaculty.getSubjectList();
        List<Faculty> lsFaculty = oSubject.getFacultyList();

        lstSubject.remove(oSubject);
        lsFaculty.remove(oFaculty);

        em.merge(oSubject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error :- " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marco i did it in stateless local session bean

Comment: what about my OWN table? Do u know something about it?